# Adding Video Tag in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, html5-video

I have an iframe inside Div in which i want to add video . I have added the URL path for the video correctly but not getting video on the screen neither i am getting any error on the browser console.Here is the HTML for the whole..

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
<iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <video id='video-player' autoplay preload='metadata' controls>
  <source src="Video/Sapno.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Please help me in displaying the video to my website ..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use iframe here, If you remove the iframe it will work, If you need the iframe from any reason you need to put "src" attribute in the iframe with link to the video.

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
 <video id='video-player' autoplay preload='metadata' controls>
  <source src="Video/Sapno.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your this Code and i am able to see the video but i have to use iframe to make this video suited to my website ..Could you provide me the code for that one also ..Thansk

Comment: try somthing like this: <iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="Video/Sapno.MP4">
</iframe>

Comment: I tried this code but with this my video is automatically getting downloaded ..but video is not getting displayed in webpage..Please see the below posted code for example..

Comment: `<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="Video/Sapno.MP4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate HTML page (let's say `second.html`) containing the `<video>` element and now call that page within the iframe as follows: `<iframe src="second.html" ... ></iframe>`.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video src="/video/demo.mp4" width="200" height="100" controls>

<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.</p>
</video>
```